# How can I use GCP free credit to deploy Hadoop?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-hadoop

How can I use the [Google Cloud Platform free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/) to test a Hadoop cluster? What are the most important things I should keep in mind if I try this? Will I be charged during the free Google Cloud Platform trial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free trial should allow you to create a modest Hadoop cluster and run a variety of jobs including MR, Hive, or Pig. The credit which comes with the trial should allow you to run a cluster free for a period of time. The cluster will utilize the budget which comes with the free trial. There are a few things to keep in mind about the trial and a Hadoop cluster, however.

1. If you have already used some services as a part of your trial then your remaining budget for a Hadoop cluster will be smaller.
2. Since you will likely create a cluster with multiple machines, I recommend you keep an eye on your remaining budget and delete your clusters when not using them.
3. The trial includes 8 cores which will limit the size of the Hadoop cluster you can create.

Without details on a specific project and its needs, it's hard to estimate sizing; however, you can utilize the [bdutil script](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/bdutil) to quickly and easily create a Hadoop cluster. Additionally, bdutil allows you to [configure your deployment](https://cloud.google.com/hadoop/setting-up-a-hadoop-cluster) to adjust the instance type you use and the number of workers you provision.

The free trial would work best with a small project and I'd recommend using a small number of workers (2) and a modest instance type to conserve the resources in the free trial.